# How to concatenate month and day from full-format dates in pig

Tags: date, datetime, apache-pig, concatenation

I uploaded a names column and a dates column in PIG that appear in the following format:
'yyyy / MM / dd HH: mm: ss'. I want to show the column of names and a column that displays only the month and day from the date, in this format: MM / dd.
How can I do this?

It's a code I tried in several ways but it did not work. I also want to display the column of names with the date column in MM/dd format:
From "MonthDay1" it does not work . **There is error 1200: " mismatched input 'CONCAT' expecting SEMI_COLON".**

```
 New1 = LOAD '/user/cloudera/file1' USING PigStorage(',') as (names1:chararray, date1:chararray);
    NewDates1 = foreach New1 generate ToDate(date1,'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss')
    as (date_time1:DateTime );
    DUMP NewDates1;
    MonthDay1= foreach NewDates1 generate
    CONCAT((chararray)GetMonth(date_time1),
    CONCAT('-',CONCAT((chararray)GetDay(date_time1))));
    DUMP MonthDay1;
```

**Also I try this code has this error:**

```
 MonthDay1= Foreach NewDates1 generate * CONCAT((Chararray)GetMonth(date_time1),CONCAT(+'- '+(Chararray)GetDay(date_time1))) as MonthDay1:Chararray;
```

Comment: What does it mean that it does not work? Are there any error messages or warnings? What is the output? Please include as much detail as possible.

Comment: Please use [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56026707/edit) link to include this information in question, not in comments.